# Signing transaction return invalid hash with wallet connect on trust wallet iOS

Tags: raw-transaction, walletconnect, trustwallet

I'm trying to sign a transaction from my Dapp with wallet connect on trust wallet.
Transaction data is something looks like this:

```
{
  data: "0x731133e9000000000000000000000000f5bf2d36c2a5dad449630d1e5550a90604ac12910000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001286000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  from: "0xf5BF2d36C2A5Dad449630d1E5550a90604Ac1291",
  gasLimit: "0x493e0",
  gasPrice: "0x700014a8c",
  nonce: "0xa",
  to: "0x8c0418db865964ca3f6d04f1d6356cc7f896c73f" 
}
```

but signed transaction hash that returned is invalid.

```
02f9011381890a850700014a87850700014a87830493e0948c0418db865964ca3f6d04f1d6356cc7f896c73f80b8a4731133e9000000000000000000000000f5bf2d36c2a5dad449630d1e5550a90604ac12910000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001286000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c080a05c2bb8a56f03e275f4ad623c176a7fa93c9879d63b29c9e98336435f72073e70a06fad8dac313291877e91c324aa82d3d4774a4755d4fac96f8a74cc2cfd1a4fda
```

This is works well on trust wallet's android but not on iOS.

Comment: How are you signing the transaction? The returned value looks like an encoded transaction.